# How i can know what device i have?

Tags: iphone, ios, appdelegate, uiapplication

I have two storyboard with size for iphone 5 and size for iphone 4. All this device have 6 IOS. So i have my code for check version of IOS ...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{


    // 1
    UIStoryboard * mainStoryboard = nil ;
    if ( SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO ( @ "6.0" ) ) {
        mainStoryboard = [ UIStoryboard storyboardWithName : @ "iPhones6.0" bundle : nil ] ;
    } else {
        mainStoryboard = [ UIStoryboard storyboardWithName : @ "iPhones3-5" bundle : nil ] ;
    }

    // 2
    self.window = [ [ UIWindow alloc ] initWithFrame : [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ] ] ;
    self.window.rootViewController = [ mainStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController ] ;
    [ self.window makeKeyAndVisible ] ;




    return YES;
}
```

If i have iphone 4 with 6 iOS and iphone also 6 IOS, i have big size display and for iPhone but for iphone 4 not work. SO how can i know what device i used, for make checking for model.

Comment: Do you really need 2 storyboards? What doesn't work if you use auto-resizing / auto-layout?

Comment: Checking the version of iOS or checking the hardware model is never the proper way to handle things like this.

Comment: Because on the second storyboard i must change some information or position of buttons etc..for me when i have two story - comfortable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not select your storyboard according to iOS version but select it according to the screen size. Like this

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    if (screenBounds.size.height == 568) {
        //device is iphone 5
        //add storyboard that have large screen (320*568)
    } else {
          //device is iphone 4
          //add story board that have small screen (320*480)

    }
```

Because it does matter which iOS is it when we displaying our screen it depend on iPhone Screen Size.

You can also differentiate iPhone and iPad using this code

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] ==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
      //device is iPhone
    }
else
    {
      //device is iPad
    }
```

And for differentiate which iOS version in your device you can use this code,

```
float currentVersion = 6.0;

if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= currentVersion)
{
    //device have iOS 6 or above
}else{
   //device have iOS 5.1 or belove
}
```

Comment: Don't use screenBound for this, it's bad practice. For example new device may have a other screen height.Apple recommends not to become attached to the coordinates.

Comment: @Anton At-least for now its a perfect way. and if new device is introduce with new device screen than we have to change some settings in our app. As we have changed when iPhone 5 introduce we have added Default-568.png file other wise in iPhone 5 our screen will display small, and also if apple introduce new device with new iOS than `maybe` some method will be deprecated so we have to think about that right now? No, I said we can use this method at current condition and let the future be folded.

Answer (score 2):

**UIDevice+CKHardware.h**

```
// The MIT License (MIT)
//
// Copyright (c) 2013 Erica Sadun
//
// Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
// of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
// in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
// to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
// copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
// furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
//
// The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
// all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
//
// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
// IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
// FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
// AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
// LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
// OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
// THE SOFTWARE.

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#define IFPGA_NAMESTRING                @"iFPGA"

#define IPHONE_1G_NAMESTRING            @"iPhone 1G"
#define IPHONE_3G_NAMESTRING            @"iPhone 3G"
#define IPHONE_3GS_NAMESTRING           @"iPhone 3GS" 
#define IPHONE_4_NAMESTRING             @"iPhone 4" 
#define IPHONE_4S_NAMESTRING            @"iPhone 4S"
#define IPHONE_5_NAMESTRING             @"iPhone 5"
#define IPHONE_UNKNOWN_NAMESTRING       @"Unknown iPhone"

#define IPOD_1G_NAMESTRING              @"iPod touch 1G"
#define IPOD_2G_NAMESTRING              @"iPod touch 2G"
#define IPOD_3G_NAMESTRING              @"iPod touch 3G"
#define IPOD_4G_NAMESTRING              @"iPod touch 4G"
#define IPOD_UNKNOWN_NAMESTRING         @"Unknown iPod"

#define IPAD_1G_NAMESTRING              @"iPad 1G"
#define IPAD_2G_NAMESTRING              @"iPad 2G"
#define IPAD_3G_NAMESTRING              @"iPad 3G"
#define IPAD_4G_NAMESTRING              @"iPad 4G"
#define IPAD_UNKNOWN_NAMESTRING         @"Unknown iPad"

#define APPLETV_2G_NAMESTRING           @"Apple TV 2G"
#define APPLETV_3G_NAMESTRING           @"Apple TV 3G"
#define APPLETV_4G_NAMESTRING           @"Apple TV 4G"
#define APPLETV_UNKNOWN_NAMESTRING      @"Unknown Apple TV"

#define IOS_FAMILY_UNKNOWN_DEVICE       @"Unknown iOS device"

#define SIMULATOR_NAMESTRING            @"iPhone Simulator"
#define SIMULATOR_IPHONE_NAMESTRING     @"iPhone Simulator"
#define SIMULATOR_IPAD_NAMESTRING       @"iPad Simulator"
#define SIMULATOR_APPLETV_NAMESTRING    @"Apple TV Simulator" // :)

typedef enum {
    UIDeviceUnknown,

    UIDeviceSimulator,
    UIDeviceSimulatoriPhone,
    UIDeviceSimulatoriPad,
    UIDeviceSimulatorAppleTV,

    UIDevice1GiPhone,
    UIDevice3GiPhone,
    UIDevice3GSiPhone,
    UIDevice4iPhone,
    UIDevice4SiPhone,
    UIDevice5iPhone,

    UIDevice1GiPod,
    UIDevice2GiPod,
    UIDevice3GiPod,
    UIDevice4GiPod,

    UIDevice1GiPad,
    UIDevice2GiPad,
    UIDevice3GiPad,
    UIDevice4GiPad,

    UIDeviceAppleTV2,
    UIDeviceAppleTV3,
    UIDeviceAppleTV4,

    UIDeviceUnknowniPhone,
    UIDeviceUnknowniPod,
    UIDeviceUnknowniPad,
    UIDeviceUnknownAppleTV,
    UIDeviceIFPGA,

} UIDevicePlatform;

typedef enum {
    UIDeviceFamilyiPhone,
    UIDeviceFamilyiPod,
    UIDeviceFamilyiPad,
    UIDeviceFamilyAppleTV,
    UIDeviceFamilyUnknown,

} UIDeviceFamily;

@interface UIDevice (CKHardware)
- (NSString *) platform;
- (NSString *) hwmodel;
- (NSUInteger) platformType;
- (NSString *) platformString;

- (NSUInteger) cpuFrequency;
- (NSUInteger) busFrequency;
- (NSUInteger) cpuCount;
- (NSUInteger) totalMemory;
- (NSUInteger) userMemory;

- (NSNumber *) totalDiskSpace;
- (NSNumber *) freeDiskSpace;

- (CGFloat) appUsedSpace;

- (NSString *) macaddress;

- (BOOL) hasRetinaDisplay;
- (UIDeviceFamily) deviceFamily;
@end
```

**UIDevice+CKHardware.m**

```
// The MIT License (MIT)
//
// Copyright (c) 2013 Erica Sadun, Emanuele Vulcano, Kevin Ballard/Eridius, Ryandjohnson, Matt Brown
//
// Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
// of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
// in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
// to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
// copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
// furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
//
// The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
// all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
//
// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
// IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
// FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
// AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
// LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
// OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
// THE SOFTWARE.

#include <sys/socket.h> // Per msqr
#include <sys/sysctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <net/if_dl.h>

#import "UIDevice+CKHardware.h"

@implementation UIDevice (CKHardware)
/*
 Platforms

 iFPGA ->        ??

 iPhone1,1 ->    iPhone 1G, M68
 iPhone1,2 ->    iPhone 3G, N82
 iPhone2,1 ->    iPhone 3GS, N88
 iPhone3,1 ->    iPhone 4/AT&T, N89
 iPhone3,2 ->    iPhone 4/Other Carrier?, ??
 iPhone3,3 ->    iPhone 4/Verizon, TBD
 iPhone4,1 ->    (iPhone 4S/GSM), TBD
 iPhone4,2 ->    (iPhone 4S/CDMA), TBD
 iPhone4,3 ->    (iPhone 4S/???)
 iPhone5,1 ->    iPhone Next Gen, TBD
 iPhone5,1 ->    iPhone Next Gen, TBD
 iPhone5,1 ->    iPhone Next Gen, TBD

 iPod1,1   ->    iPod touch 1G, N45
 iPod2,1   ->    iPod touch 2G, N72
 iPod2,2   ->    Unknown, ??
 iPod3,1   ->    iPod touch 3G, N18
 iPod4,1   ->    iPod touch 4G, N80

 // Thanks NSForge
 iPad1,1   ->    iPad 1G, WiFi and 3G, K48
 iPad2,1   ->    iPad 2G, WiFi, K93
 iPad2,2   ->    iPad 2G, GSM 3G, K94
 iPad2,3   ->    iPad 2G, CDMA 3G, K95
 iPad3,1   ->    (iPad 3G, WiFi)
 iPad3,2   ->    (iPad 3G, GSM)
 iPad3,3   ->    (iPad 3G, CDMA)
 iPad4,1   ->    (iPad 4G, WiFi)
 iPad4,2   ->    (iPad 4G, GSM)
 iPad4,3   ->    (iPad 4G, CDMA)

 AppleTV2,1 ->   AppleTV 2, K66
 AppleTV3,1 ->   AppleTV 3, ??

 i386, x86_64 -> iPhone Simulator
*/


#pragma mark sysctlbyname utils
- (NSString *) getSysInfoByName:(char *)typeSpecifier
{
    size_t size;
    sysctlbyname(typeSpecifier, NULL, &size, NULL, 0);

    char *answer = malloc(size);
    sysctlbyname(typeSpecifier, answer, &size, NULL, 0);

    NSString *results = [NSString stringWithCString:answer encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    free(answer);
    return results;
}

- (NSString *) platform
{
    return [self getSysInfoByName:"hw.machine"];
}


// Thanks, Tom Harrington (Atomicbird)
- (NSString *) hwmodel
{
    return [self getSysInfoByName:"hw.model"];
}

#pragma mark sysctl utils
- (NSUInteger) getSysInfo: (uint) typeSpecifier
{
    size_t size = sizeof(int);
    int results;
    int mib[2] = {CTL_HW, typeSpecifier};
    sysctl(mib, 2, &results, &size, NULL, 0);
    return (NSUInteger) results;
}

- (NSUInteger) cpuFrequency
{
    return [self getSysInfo:HW_CPU_FREQ];
}

- (NSUInteger) busFrequency
{
    return [self getSysInfo:HW_BUS_FREQ];
}

- (NSUInteger) cpuCount
{
    return [self getSysInfo:HW_NCPU];
}

- (NSUInteger) totalMemory
{
    return [self getSysInfo:HW_PHYSMEM];
}

- (NSUInteger) userMemory
{
    return [self getSysInfo:HW_USERMEM];
}

- (NSUInteger) maxSocketBufferSize
{
    return [self getSysInfo:KIPC_MAXSOCKBUF];
}

#pragma mark file system -- Thanks Joachim Bean!

/*
 extern NSString *NSFileSystemSize;
 extern NSString *NSFileSystemFreeSize;
 extern NSString *NSFileSystemNodes;
 extern NSString *NSFileSystemFreeNodes;
 extern NSString *NSFileSystemNumber;
*/

- (NSNumber *) totalDiskSpace
{
    NSDictionary *fattributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:NSHomeDirectory() error:nil];
    return [fattributes objectForKey:NSFileSystemSize];
}

- (NSNumber *) freeDiskSpace
{
    NSDictionary *fattributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:NSHomeDirectory() error:nil];
    return [fattributes objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize];
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

- (CGFloat) appUsedSpace {
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [paths lastObject];

    NSArray *filesArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:&error];
    NSEnumerator *filesEnumerator = [filesArray objectEnumerator];
    NSString *fileName;
    unsigned long long int fileSize = 0;

    while (fileName = [filesEnumerator nextObject]) {
        NSString *fullPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
        NSDictionary *fileDictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:fullPath error:&error];
        fileSize += [fileDictionary fileSize];
    }

    return fileSize;
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma mark platform type and name utils
- (NSUInteger) platformType
{
    NSString *platform = [self platform];

    // The ever mysterious iFPGA
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iFPGA"])        return UIDeviceIFPGA;

    // iPhone
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"])    return UIDevice1GiPhone;
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"])    return UIDevice3GiPhone;
    if ([platform hasPrefix:@"iPhone2"])            return UIDevice3GSiPhone;
    if ([platform hasPrefix:@"iPhone3"])            return UIDevice4iPhone;
    if ([platform hasPrefix:@"iPhone4"])            return UIDevice4SiPhone;
    if ([platform hasPrefix:@"iPhone5"])            return UIDevice5iPhone;

    // iPod
    if ([platform hasPrefix:@"iPod1"])              return UIDevice1GiPod;
    if ([platform hasPrefix:@"iPod2"])              return UIDevice2GiPod;
    if ([platform hasPrefix:@"iPod3"])              return UIDevice3GiPod;
    if ([platform hasPrefix:@"iPod4"])              return UIDevice4GiPod;

    // iPad
    if ([platform hasPrefix:@"iPad1"])              return UIDevice1GiPad;
    if ([platform hasPrefix:@"iPad2"])              return UIDevice2GiPad;
    if ([platform hasPrefix:@"iPad3"])              return UIDevice3GiPad;
    if ([platform hasPrefix:@"iPad4"])              return UIDevice4GiPad;

    // Apple TV
    if ([platform hasPrefix:@"AppleTV2"])           return UIDeviceAppleTV2;
    if ([platform hasPrefix:@"AppleTV3"])           return UIDeviceAppleTV3;

    if ([platform hasPrefix:@"iPhone"])             return UIDeviceUnknowniPhone;
    if ([platform hasPrefix:@"iPod"])               return UIDeviceUnknowniPod;
    if ([platform hasPrefix:@"iPad"])               return UIDeviceUnknowniPad;
    if ([platform hasPrefix:@"AppleTV"])            return UIDeviceUnknownAppleTV;

    // Simulator thanks Jordan Breeding
    if ([platform hasSuffix:@"86"] || [platform isEqual:@"x86_64"])
    {
        BOOL smallerScreen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width < 768;
        return smallerScreen ? UIDeviceSimulatoriPhone : UIDeviceSimulatoriPad;
    }

    return UIDeviceUnknown;
}

- (NSString *) platformString
{
    switch ([self platformType])
    {
        case UIDevice1GiPhone: return IPHONE_1G_NAMESTRING;
        case UIDevice3GiPhone: return IPHONE_3G_NAMESTRING;
        case UIDevice3GSiPhone: return IPHONE_3GS_NAMESTRING;
        case UIDevice4iPhone: return IPHONE_4_NAMESTRING;
        case UIDevice4SiPhone: return IPHONE_4S_NAMESTRING;
        case UIDevice5iPhone: return IPHONE_5_NAMESTRING;
        case UIDeviceUnknowniPhone: return IPHONE_UNKNOWN_NAMESTRING;

        case UIDevice1GiPod: return IPOD_1G_NAMESTRING;
        case UIDevice2GiPod: return IPOD_2G_NAMESTRING;
        case UIDevice3GiPod: return IPOD_3G_NAMESTRING;
        case UIDevice4GiPod: return IPOD_4G_NAMESTRING;
        case UIDeviceUnknowniPod: return IPOD_UNKNOWN_NAMESTRING;

        case UIDevice1GiPad : return IPAD_1G_NAMESTRING;
        case UIDevice2GiPad : return IPAD_2G_NAMESTRING;
        case UIDevice3GiPad : return IPAD_3G_NAMESTRING;
        case UIDevice4GiPad : return IPAD_4G_NAMESTRING;
        case UIDeviceUnknowniPad : return IPAD_UNKNOWN_NAMESTRING;

        case UIDeviceAppleTV2 : return APPLETV_2G_NAMESTRING;
        case UIDeviceAppleTV3 : return APPLETV_3G_NAMESTRING;
        case UIDeviceAppleTV4 : return APPLETV_4G_NAMESTRING;
        case UIDeviceUnknownAppleTV: return APPLETV_UNKNOWN_NAMESTRING;

        case UIDeviceSimulator: return SIMULATOR_NAMESTRING;
        case UIDeviceSimulatoriPhone: return SIMULATOR_IPHONE_NAMESTRING;
        case UIDeviceSimulatoriPad: return SIMULATOR_IPAD_NAMESTRING;
        case UIDeviceSimulatorAppleTV: return SIMULATOR_APPLETV_NAMESTRING;

        case UIDeviceIFPGA: return IFPGA_NAMESTRING;

        default: return IOS_FAMILY_UNKNOWN_DEVICE;
    }
}

- (BOOL) hasRetinaDisplay
{
    return ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.0f);
}

- (UIDeviceFamily) deviceFamily
{
    NSString *platform = [self platform];
    if ([platform hasPrefix:@"iPhone"]) return UIDeviceFamilyiPhone;
    if ([platform hasPrefix:@"iPod"]) return UIDeviceFamilyiPod;
    if ([platform hasPrefix:@"iPad"]) return UIDeviceFamilyiPad;
    if ([platform hasPrefix:@"AppleTV"]) return UIDeviceFamilyAppleTV;

    return UIDeviceFamilyUnknown;
}

#pragma mark MAC addy
// Return the local MAC addy
// Courtesy of FreeBSD hackers email list
// Accidentally munged during previous update. Fixed thanks to mlamb.
- (NSString *) macaddress
{
    int                 mib[6];
    size_t              len;
    char                *buf;
    unsigned char       *ptr;
    struct if_msghdr    *ifm;
    struct sockaddr_dl  *sdl;

    mib[0] = CTL_NET;
    mib[1] = AF_ROUTE;
    mib[2] = 0;
    mib[3] = AF_LINK;
    mib[4] = NET_RT_IFLIST;

    if ((mib[5] = if_nametoindex("en0")) == 0) {
        printf("Error: if_nametoindex error\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    if (sysctl(mib, 6, NULL, &len, NULL, 0) < 0) {
        printf("Error: sysctl, take 1\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    if ((buf = malloc(len)) == NULL) {
        printf("Error: Memory allocation error\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    if (sysctl(mib, 6, buf, &len, NULL, 0) < 0) {
        printf("Error: sysctl, take 2\n");
        free(buf); // Thanks, Remy "Psy" Demerest
        return NULL;
    }

    ifm = (struct if_msghdr *)buf;
    sdl = (struct sockaddr_dl *)(ifm + 1);
    ptr = (unsigned char *)LLADDR(sdl);
    NSString *outstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X", *ptr, *(ptr+1), *(ptr+2), *(ptr+3), *(ptr+4), *(ptr+5)];

    free(buf);
    return outstring;
}

@end
```

Happy coding ^_^

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking correctly in the first place.

You could've used the **UIScreen** to get the size of the screen and determine which device is used.
Also if you are developing for **iOS 6** then you only need **1 Storyboard** and you can use **Autolayout** option for the controllers and create **NSLayoutContrains** from the interface builder.

THis should be a lot easier than having 2 stroyboards for each iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

There is **no need** to have 2 storyboards for 4inch devices (iPhone 5) and 3.5inch devices (iPhone 4S and lower).

The iPad requires a separate storyboard as the screen is far larger, but for an extra 88 pixels in height on iPhone 5, theres not really a lot more you can fit on as extra.

[AutoLayout](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=202) from iOS6 solves this problem, even the old Autoresizing properties solves this.

If you have an extra view (or any UI element) just for the iPhone 5, then simply detect the screen height as suggested by Dilip and if it's not iPhone 5 then hide the UI element using `myElement.hidden = YES;`.

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
if (screenBounds.size.height <= 480) {
    myElement.hidden = YES;
}
```

In Storyboard view of Xcode theres a button on the iPhone storyboard which switches between 3.5 inch and 4 inch so you can adjust components positions to suit the device as shown below on the left.

[image]